# Getting started with GDAL?

Tags: gdal, c++, references

I'm completely new to GDAL and I'm going to use it to work with satellite images, DEMs, etc.

I have some experience working with Visual C++ and the OpenCV library. And in fact my goal is to combine OpenCV, GDAL and OpenGL for developing software for remote-sensing purposes. The programming language will be Visual C++.

My problem is that in searching the net, I couldn't find a good book for learning GDAL and in fact most of the open source codes found in the Net are written in the Python language but I'm not familiar with this language and I don't want to get familiar.  Surely I know that the best language for programming with GDAL is Python but the rules of the company where I work force me to use Visual C++.

So with the conditions mentioned above, **what do you suggest as the best way to study GDAL?**

The first piece of program that I want to write would be:

1. Read a satellite image file with the help of the GDAL library.
2. Extract image's header information.
3. Write a program to  apply a Gaussian filter on the image that was read in step 1.
4. Convert the image read in step 1 to an image of the OpenCV family to do some other processing.